# Should I buy DDR3 or DDR3L RAM for late 2012 MacBook pro 13 inch?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

I have a MacBook Pro 13", late 2012 model.

This MacBook has 2x2gb 1600MHz DDR3 RAM. I am planning to upgrade it to 8GB of RAM.

I am wondering, should I buy DDR3 or DDR3L type of RAM?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a RAM upgrade guide located [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201165). For your computer(MBP 13" mid-2012),  it provides this information:

[image: RAM info]

Comment: Note that while this computer only officially supports 8GB of RAM, Other World Computing (www.macsales.com) suggests that up to 16 GB of RAM can be installed without problems.

Comment: I already checked it out.  I wanted to know whether i can put a ddr3l ram in it?

Comment: Yes you can, theoretically, but I don't know why you would. Apple doesn't officially support it, but theoretically ddr3l is backwards compatible with ddr3.